# Merge faces not working

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image: https://i.snag.gy/Y54DJp.jpg]

Limited dissolve / merge / non of these options are getting rid of the coplanar lines in the table top here (with the holes in it).

FILES: [image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you won't get rid of a lot of edges with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* because you need almost all of these edges to keep your holes.

Here is an explanation of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are faces inside of the mesh that you need to delete first.